# Multiple Column Duplicate Criteria

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server. This is my sample data set:

```
IDNO| Consigment | SO_Number | Acc Number | OfficeNumber|PL9    |Remarks
--- | -----------| ----------| -----------| ------------|-------|-------
1   | AA12345MY  | 1024450191| 8800400431 |B213         |W449401|Stay
2   | AA12345MY  | 1024450192| 8800400431 |B213         |W449401|Remove
3   | BA12345MY  | 1024460121| 8800400726 |K678         |W229790|Stay
4   | BA12345MY  | 1024460124| 8800400726 |K678         |W229790|Remove
```

I want to put a remarks on row 2 and 4 as it is a duplicates.

Duplicate criteria must match these 4 columns:

1. Consigment
2. Acc Number
3. OfficeNumber
4. PL9

I am removing the youngest SO number (which one is the latest)

I haven't got a clue on how to start as I never found a perfect reference

Regards,

Fadlisham Fadzil

Answer (score 2):

One approach here to create a CTE which labels duplicate records and then delete from that CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Consigment, [Acc Number], OfficeNumber, PL9
                           ORDER BY SO_Number) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: hai - so i run it

it didnt came out as a result - i am guessing it delete from the "yourTable"

so whats left is the NonDuplicated item?